# INSERT with VALUES and subquery, postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I need to insert several rows at once, and values for some columns should be taken from ‘VALUES’, and for some columns, I would need to use a subquery.
Assuming that subquery will return exactly the same amount of rows as I’m trying to insert. Something like this:

```
WITH subq AS (
   --returns 3 rows
   SELECT param FROM tbl2 WHERE status = 1  
)
INSERT INTO tbl1 (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
('col1_val1', 'col2_val1', subq.row1.param),
('col1_val2', 'col2_val2', subq.row2.param),
('col1_val3', 'col2_val3', subq.row3.param)
```

Comment: 1) If you have any hope of making this work the `WITH` query is going to need an `ORDER BY` as SQL data is unordered by default. 2) You need to tell us what the relationship is between `subq.param` and the other values.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the text to the  CTE and make a `INSERT INTO SELECT`

```
WITH CTE as 
(
(SELECT 'col1_val1', 'col2_val1', param FROM tbl2 WHERE status = 1 ORDER By params LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'col1_val2', 'col2_val2', param FROM tbl2 WHERE status = 1 ORDER By params LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'col1_val3', 'col2_val3', param FROM tbl2 WHERE status = 1 ORDER By params LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2))
INSERT INTO tbl1 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```